# How to redirect old URL to URL but both URL's still work while having pretty URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my old Url

```
http://localhost/site/viewactors.php?name=G%20Eazy%20ft%20Blac%20Youngsta%20and%20BlocBoy%20JB%20Drop
```

But the new url is going to look like this:

```
http://localhost/site/viewactors/G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop
```

With `.htaccess` how do i redirect direct the new url to the correct same viewactors page with the query but still if someones visits the old url it will still also work

this is what i have currently

```
RewriteCond %{viewactors}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{viewactors}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ /viewactors.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^viewactors/(.*)$ viewactors.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: For this to work i need to add a ? in front of the name like this  viewactors/?G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop

Comment: use `?` if you want optional trailing slash something like that `RewriteRule ^viewactors/(.*)/?$`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `.htaccess` code like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ viewactors.php?name=$1
```

From the below url

```
http://localhost/site/viewactors/G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop
```

Now you can get the `G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop` value like this( In `viewactors.php` file)

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: This one doe not pick up the query string as it returns null /viewactors/G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop

Comment: Where did you kept your `.htaccess` file ? It should be in `site` folder.

Comment: Yes it is in the site folder, just can't seem to be able to pass the query

Comment: It picks up the query string when you add a question mark the front like this: ?G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop

Answer (score 0):

try this out, hope it will solve your query :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ viewactors.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you've read the question. Explain why you're using `show.php?slug=`?

Comment: i copied above one from one of my .htaccess., that why its show.php. changed it. see again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^viewactors/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /viewactors.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And inside the page viewactors.php, you can put this code at the top of the page, to retrieve the name:

```
$param = explode("/",str_replace("'", "''", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
if(isset($param[count($param) - 1]) && $param[count($param) - 1] != ""){
    $name = $param[count($param) - 1];
    echo "Viewactor name = " . $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out this works for me:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^viewactors.php/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/? viewactors.php?&name=$1 [L]

I end up with a URL that is like this: http://localhost/site/viewactors/G-Eazy-ft-Blac-Youngsta-and-BlocBoy-JB-Drop

and also the old URL still works